# Fab icon size change

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

Why isn't this simple code not working?
Initially I set size of fab icon to mini using the xml code `app:fabSize="mini"`

Then I used this little piece to java code to shift sizes interchangebly

```
  final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(fab.SIZE_MINI == 1)
                {
                    fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_NORMAL);
                }
                else 
                    fab.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
            }
        });
    }
```

It does change to normal size upon first click but after that it doesn't change back. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should check with `fab.getSize() == FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI`

Comment: Wow that worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check with `fab.getSize() == FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI`